# Why is razor not adding the proper bootstrap classes to form controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've just downloaded VS 2013 because its new native support to the Bootstrap framework.

I create my forms, but they look different to original bootstrap ones. Problem is that it seems as razor and its "EditorFor" method, is not adding the "form-control" class needed for bootstrap.

I could add it as an html parameter, but then I would have to do that for each and every text field in my site.

How can I fix/modify Razor for it to automatically add this class for this objects?

Comment: Visual Studio itself makes little difference to what you're asking. Its the MVC libraries/helpers that matter. AFAIK they don't "natively support bootstrap".. because that would mean that every time you used `EditorFor` it would add unwanted classes to controls if you weren't using bootstrap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end as definitely it's not an error, it's just that .NET decided not to include this. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap

The easiest way I foudn was using Jquery and adding the class to all the field that I need to in my case all the text-boxes en select lists.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $(".text-box").addClass("form-control");
    $("select").addClass("form-control");
</script>
}
```

Comment: This seems too messy to me. I would suggest not using razor and adding the class as plain html. For me, this creates greater flexibility if I want to add a framework such as angular to the form.

Answer (score 2):

Try using TextBoxFor.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {style="border:1px solid red;"})
```

This works. and if you want to add any class

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {@class="fooo"})
```

should work.

Comment: It work, but only with TextBoxFor if I use the default EditorFor it does not work. Which Means that I would have to replace it all over my app...

Comment: Yeah, as you mentioned, they promise to get editorfor work in mvc 5.1 but didnt quite well. Better if you go with this. It is proven to work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML classes must always be added manually. Nothing will do this for you automatically by default.

There are a few options for you:

- Put the classes in the htmlAttributes, as you mentioned.
- Create [razor helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) or [Html helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).
- Use a library like [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/) (I think this costs?)

Comment: You seem to be right, I've just found this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap but anyways I can't get it to work even "adding" the class as they said, it just not get added.